# How to get the size of a Winforms Form titlebar height?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So if it's toolwindow or a minimizable form, I want to be able to get its height programmatically.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can determine titlebar height for both tool-windows and normal forms by using:

```
Rectangle screenRectangle = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);

int titleHeight = screenRectangle.Top - this.Top;
```

Where 'this' is your form.

ClientRectangle returns the bounds of the client area of your form.  RectangleToScreen converts this to screen coordinates which is the same coordinate system as the Form screen location.

Comment: I believe this is the better solution. SystemInformation.CaptionHeight will only give the Title Bar height for a top level window (I believe), and would not work for ToolWindows, so this is a little more generic.

Comment: +1 from me, I too believe this is the better solution. 'SystemInformation.CaptionHeight' does not seem to work with ToolWindows.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is correct.  Aero lies about the window position for appcompat reasons.  Its fat borders are a tricky problem.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think about this. So you think there is no way to do this? I am really surprised then.

Comment: I don't know about the possible Aero problem, but this technique was userful for me to determine the form's title bar height and border width when the form is a Developer Express XtraForm, where these factors depend on the skin that the user has selected.

Comment: The call to RectangleToScreen ought to be prefixed with 'this.' for completeness. In my case I was adding a form with an internal user control:<pre>
                    Rectangle formRectangle = myForm.RectangleToScreen(myForm.ClientRectangle);
                    int titleHeight = formRectangle.Top - myForm.Top;
                    myForm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(myControl.Size.Width, myControl.Size.Height + titleHeight);</pre>

Comment: It seems when a window is maximized windows will cut off some pixel of the title bar. Is there a way to figure out the height when the window is maximized as well? https://imgur.com/a/HCFAnN7

Answer (score 6):

There is an additional wrinkle in case your form is a view in an MDI application. In that case RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle) returns coordinates relative not to Form itself (as one might expect) but with respect to MainForm which hosts MDIClient control hosting the Form.

You may to account for that by

```
Point pnt = new Point(0, 0);
Point corner = this.PointToScreen(pnt); // upper left in MainFrame coordinates
Point origin = this.Parent.PointToScreen(pnt); // MDIClient upperleft in MainFrame coordinates
int titleBarHeight = corner.Y - origin.Y - this.Location.Y;
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to change the height of the form so that it was just below one of the controls, I noticed that

```
  int titleHeight = this.Height - screenRectangle.Height;
```

returns **39** while the accepted answer:

```
  int titleHeight =  screenRectangle.Top - this.Top;
```

returns **31**

maybe because of form's bottom border.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the TitleBarsize:

```
form.ClientRectangle.Height - form.Height;
```

Comment: Not exactly. This gives you the height of the *non-client area*. In practice, this may be the same as the height of the title bar if there are no other non-client areas, but it is not necessarily the same. Semantically, then, the code is wrong.

Comment: It's just wrong, period.  He's subtracting the form from the client area.  That's backwards.

Answer (score 0):

To fix S. Norman's answer that simply has his minuend and subtrahend switched, the following is the simplest answer:

> int HeightOfTheTitleBar_ofThis = this.Height - this.ClientRectangle.Height;

BTW, the standard hard coded title bar is 25dpi which is the minimum height and can be changed to a maximum of 50dpi.

OK OK,... yes, it is technically incorrect As stated by Cody Grey but it works and should get the same answer as the accepted answer. No need to create a rectangle.