# Coordinates of the title bar

Tags: vb.net, windows

I was just wondering if anybody knew what the coordinates of the title bar is. I need to draw a rectangle the same size as the title bar but I don't know the exact size of the title bar itself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't like this because it involves messy hwnds BUT you should be able to do it with old win32 api calls, specifically:

1) Call GetDesktopWindow to find the parents of the parents

GetDestopWindow
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504(v=vs.85).aspx

2) Then use GetWindow (to navigate to the title bar window)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx

3) Finally GetWindowRect on the title bar hwnd (handle).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx

If the window you want to find the title bar size of is part of the form you have control of you can use its Handle property and side step step #1 and use the form as your start in step #2.

Answer (score 1):

From:

[How to get the size of a Winforms Form titlebar height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022660/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-winforms-form-titlebar-height)

Rectangle screenRectangle=RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);

int titleHeight = screenRectangle.Top - this.Top;

This should give you what you need to get going.

Comment: There isnt just a universal title bar size that I could just draw my own rectangle for?

Comment: I don't think so.  Try out the code above, I assume you can use the forms's width as your title bar's width, the forms top as the title bars top, and the code above should give you the title bar's height.